# fatal error: backtrace/Backtrace.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android-source

I have downloaded AOSP source using repo and now trying to build it, when i run make i get following error during the build and compilation terminates...
dalvik/vm/interp/Stack.cpp:29:33: fatal error: backtrace/Backtrace.h: No such file or directory

Regards
-MS

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the file "art/runtime/mem_map.cc" where it includes backtrace:

```
#include "backtrace/backtrace.h"
```

change to

```
#include "backtrace/Backtrace.h"
```